# Counting occurrence while changing NULL to 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this (primary key omitted for clarity):

```
events:

itemId  eventType
-----------------
  100      1
  101      1
  101      2
  102      2
  102      2
```

There are other event types but I only care about 1's and 2's. I want to find the count of these `eventType`s per `itemId`, but I also need a way to conveniently perform math on the results. For example, I want an output like this:

```
itemId  ones  twos   onesPct  twosPct
-------------------------------------
 100      1    0       1.0      0.0
 101      1    1       0.5      0.5
 102      0    2       0.0      1.0
```

In my actual application, the math I'm performing is much more complex than percentages. The dialect is T-SQL. So right now I have a query like this; I'm not that great with SQL and so the best I came up with was:

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(onest.itemId,twost.itemId) itemId,
  COALESCE(onest.n,0) ones,
  COALESCE(twost.n,0) twos,
  1.0*COALESCE(onest.n,0) / (COALESCE(onest.n,0) + COALESCE(twost.n,0)) onesPct,
  1.0*COALESCE(twost.n,0) / (COALESCE(onest.n,0) + COALESCE(twost.n,0)) twosPct
FROM
   (SELECT itemId, COUNT(*) n
    FROM events
    WHERE eventType = 1
    GROUP BY itemId) onest
FULL OUTER JOIN
   (SELECT itemId, COUNT(*) n
    FROM events
    WHERE eventType = 2 
    GROUP BY itemId) twost
ON onest.itemId = twost.itemId
```

This is working except all of the `COALESCE`s in the equations are becoming extremely unwieldy. So I have two questions:

1. Most importantly: Is there some way of converting NULLs from the outer join to 0 at a more global level, so that I don't have to keep writing e.g. `COALESCE(onest.n,0)` everywhere? From what I've seen so far, I'm not allowed to use column aliases in other column specifications, so I can't simply do e.g. `(1.0 * ones / (ones + twos)) onestPct` in the above query (unless there is a way to do this)?
2. Is there a shorter query that can accomplish this whole thing? This seems like a mess of subqueries.

I don't care too much about performance, the main task is data mining and analysis.

[Here it is on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d6e85/2).

Also, apologies for the poor title, I couldn't come up with a good short summary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you said what you are doing is more complicated than percentages, but I think regardless the key is simply a subquery.

Do your grouping work first.  When that's done, use that as the source of a query in which you do the actual math.  And of course, if it's too complex you could consider putting that subquery into a temporary table.

So here's what I would do if it were just the data you provided.

```
select itemid,
       ones,
       twos,
       ones + twos as total,
       100 * (round(ones / (ones + twos), 4)) as ones_perc,
       100 * (round(twos / (ones + twos), 4)) as twos_perc
from 
    (select itemid,
       sum(case when eventtype = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as ones,
       sum(case when eventtype = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as twos
     from a
     group by itemid)b
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I actually just came up with an almost identical query combining the other two answers here. Your answer is the most complete one. Good general advice about grouping first then calculating, too. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregate functions (`SUM()`) on `CASE` which simplifies the whole query:

```
select itemId,
  sum(case eventType when 1 then 1 else 0 end) ones,
  sum(case eventType when 2 then 1 else 0 end) twos,
  convert(float, sum(case eventType when 1 then 1 else 0 end)) / count(eventType) onesPct,
  convert(float, sum(case eventType when 2 then 1 else 0 end)) / count(eventType) twosPct
from events
group by itemId
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/904b5/5)

If there are items which don't have any events, you should either exclude them or handle percentage calculation separately as the query above will cause division by zero.

Comment: Thanks! `SUM` really seems to clean things up as far as the totals go. The issue here though is my actual math is more complex than percentages (there's a few arbitrarily complicated equations that use the two counts many times). With this, I have to use `case eventType when 1 then 1 else 0 end`, for example, every time I need to refer to the count of 1's -- my main goal, though, is to keep the equations clean.

Comment: If your math is complex, you can get the sums for ones and twos and the total count in an inner query and then use that to get the end value.

Comment: Ah, by combining this with Hafthor's suggestion, I came up with a great working query that uses `SUM`s as a subquery, and does the math in the outer one.

Comment: Accept his, no problem. I'm sure he'll enjoy 15 rep :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select itemId,ones,twos,ones/c onesPct,twos/c twosPct from (
 select itemId,sum(2-eventType) ones,sum(eventType-1) twos,sum(1.0) c from events where eventType in (1,2) group by itemId
) e
```

Comment: Interesting; so basically, you're suggesting I do one query that eliminates the nulls, *then* use that as a subquery for the main query that does all the math, correct? By combining this with Szymon's suggestion to use `SUM` I came up with a nice working query. Thanks!